# Call cvxpy Python library on Android

Tags: python, android, android-studio, cvxpy, chaquopy

I need to call python function in Android Studio.  I have tried Chaquopy and run simple program successfully. However my Python program need to import cvxpy library and it fails to import cvxpy through wheel file.  Is there other ways to call Python function in Android Studio?

Comment: you mean that Chaquopy doesn't allow you to include custom libraries? mmm strange...

Comment: @Lino I think it is scipy problem. I also ask in Chaquopy forum https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/1082#issuecomment-1909270496. Could you take a look please?

Comment: @Lino Chaquopy supports [many third-party libraries](https://chaquo.com/pypi-13.1/), but not cvxpy yet. Instructions for adding new packages are [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/tree/master/server/pypi).